# How do I make C++ choose a random phrase from several?

Tags: c++, random

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to programming and C++ and I'm trying to make a console app where you input a genre, and it chooses one of six movies in the genre.

I'm just trying to find out how to make it output one movie of around 6-10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{



    string cri, dra, rom, war, west, hor, act, scifi, thril, com, movie;
    cri = "crime";
    dra = "drama";
    rom = "romance";
    war = "war";
    west = "western";
    hor = "horror";
    act = "action";
    scifi = "scifi";
    thril = "thriller";
    com = "comedy";


    cout << "Welcome to Random Movie Shuffler. Select a genre, and you'll receive a random movie of that genre!\n" << endl;
    cin >> movie;

    if (movie == cri)
    {

        string crim;
        crim = ("movie 1", "movie 2", "movie 3", "movie 4", "movie 5", "movie 6");
    
        cout << "Check out " << crim << endl;

    }
```

Comment: Put all phrases into a vector, [shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) it, and pick the first.

Comment: Yes use a vector and std::shuffle. There is an example for `int` here but the code is  the same for std::string (well after you switch the type and fill with strings instead of ints): [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Answer (score 1):

Put the various phrases into a *vector*, and either "shuffle" that vector or simply generate a random index `[0...size-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your movies into a `std::array` or a `std::vector`, and then use the [sample](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) algorithm to pick one item at random with equal probability.

```
std::string result;
std::sample(std::begin(movies), std::end(movies), 
            std::back_inserter(result),
            1, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
```

Answer (score -2):

Make the list of strings an array and use the [rand()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function to select an entry from the array.

Example (high level):

```
const char* genres[] = {"string 1","string 2","string 3","etc..."};
genres[rand() % SIZE_OF_ARRAY_GENRES];
```

Comment: If the number of movies is fixed, `std::array` is the preferred container. Also, `rand` is not a good way to generate random numbers. There are much better techniques in the `<random>` header.

Comment: Agreed. This is more of a C answer rather than full C++.

Comment: I'm not clear why you would write a solution in C for a question in C++. They're different languages, and the code one would write in one language is often quite different from what one would write for the other. Your answer is an example of that; it's quite a poor C++ solution.

Comment: Still it is a solution and valid C++ though not idiomatic.